# Why use http status codes vs integers for http error handling?

Tags: go

I've been told in the past when evaluating http responses I should use the actual status codes vs hard typing out the integer. Is there any reason why? The only reason I can think of is that the status code is a constant.

Example:

```
if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
```

vs

```
if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
```

Comment: Some status codes are that well known (like 200 or 404) that not even linters complain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for readability more than anything else. With some of the less common codes, it's better to have something that's readable instead of making someone look it up.

Comment: Besides readability of the code, there's also the fact that searching through a code base, e.g. with grep, for a specific status code using its integer value is very likely to result in a lot of noise.